# find probability of two coins tossed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability

Throw coins until the head comes out twice.  It is assumed that the probability that head comes
 out is p and the probability that the tail comes out $q = 1-p$.
the random variables X and Y denote, respectively the number of trial required until the first and second heads are observed. 
 . At this time, the simultaneous probability distribution of $(X,Y)$ is

given as follows.

$P(X=m,Y=n) = p^2q^{n-2},    m =1,2,3,....n-1 , n=2,3....$

$0\text{ otherwise}$

1. Find the probability distribution
   of $X$ and the probability distribution of $Y$.

$P(x=m,y=n)=(1-p)^{m-1}p(1-p)^{n-m-1}p$

$P(Y=n)=\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}P(x=m,y=n)=(n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$ because m is max at n-1

2. Find $P (X = m | Y = n)= P (X = m,Y = n) / P (Y = n)$ and show that it is not related to $m$.

$P(x=m|y=n)=\frac{(1-p)^{m-1}p(1-p){n-m-1}}{P(Y=n)}$

$P(Y=n)=\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}P(x=m,y=n)=(n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$ because m is max at n-1

$P(x=m|y=n)=\frac{(1-p)^{m-1}p(1-p){n-m-1}}{(n-1)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}}=(n-1)^{-1}$

since its geometric distribution, its memoryless, so its not related to $m$(?)

3. If $Z = Y-X$, find the probability
   distribution of $Z$ and show that $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

im not sure how can i find this pmf z in discrete joint distributions?
should i make table?

Comment: To provide clarity it might be useful to add a small example. If the sequence is e.g. TTTHTTH then what value takes $X$ and what value takes $Y$?

Comment: @drhab i edit my post, $P(x=m,y=n)=(1-p)^{m-1}p(1-p)^{n-m-1}p$ ,X is number of trial until first heads, Y is number of trial after first head to second heads

Comment: Okay, but (for certainty) what is your anwer to the question posed in my comment?

Comment: @drhab its probably X= m=3, Y= n=7, since $ qqqpqqp$ and $p^2q^{n-2}=p^2q^5$  atisfy the pmf(?)

Comment: If indeed $P(X=m,Y=n)=p^2q^{n-2}$ then the PMF does not even depend on the value $m$ taken by $X$, which is weird. Did you find the PMF yourself?

Comment: @drhab the pmf for joint is stated in the problem.. "given as follows" .

Comment: I suspect that TTTHTTH gives $X=4$ and $Y=7$. This based on the description in your question. Further I was wrong in suggesting that $p^2q^{n-2}$ could not be correct (sorry for confusion).

Comment: @drhab yes it should be 4, for a i think i dont know if  probability distribution X is same as marginall distribution X or not, i think im wrong as i count the marginal one for joint distribution

Answer (score 1):

The probability distribution of $X$ is the [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) one that counts the number of *trials* needed to arrive at a success. This equipped with parameter $p$:$$P(X=m)=q^{m-1}p$$ where $m\in\{1,2,\dots\}$. I cannot find this in your attempt.

The probability distribution of $Y$ can be recognized as a sort of negative binomial distribution also counting the number of *trials*. This time the number of trials needed for reaching $2$ successes, and with:$$P(Y=n)=\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}P(X=m,Y=n)=(n-1)p^2q^{n-2}$$
for $n\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$. This part you did okay.

Also you stated correctly that $P(X=m\mid Y=n)=\frac1{n-1}$ for every integer $n\geq2$ and every $m\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$.

For finding the probability of $Z=Y-X$ be aware of the fact that $Z$ is the number of trials needed to arrive at the second succcess *if we start our counting exactly after arriving at the first success*. First we count until the first success is reached ($X$ trials needed). Then after this we start counting again (and anew) until the second success arrives ($Z$ trials needed for that). Evidently $X$ and $Z$ have the same probability distribution and also the new counting is not bothered or influenced by the result of the first. This means: $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: thankyou so much!, for $P(X=m)=q^{m-1}p$ , do you find this distribution same as finding the marginal distribution for x? and also im still not clear what is the relation between X and Y ? and if X denotes the number of trial before head appear, for example x=4, why this means qqqp , as q=failure is 3 and not 4? and for Z , is this just counting P(Y) - P(X)? so this is mean, X is for first trial until head appear, and Y is trial from start until 2 heads appear, and Z is from first heads to second heads?

Comment: We can find $P(X=m)=q^{m-1}p$ directly on base of the description (number of trials required until the first head is observed). There is no need to find as marginal distribution of $(X,Y)$. That would only make things more complicated. See it like this. We first toss until a head arrives. Let the result be TTTH. That means that $X$ has taken value $4$ and the probability on this event is $q^3p$. After this process we do it again but now name the random variable counting the trials by $Z$. This time with result TTH. That means that $Z=3$. Pasting together we find $TTTHTTH$ with $Y=7=X+Z$.

Comment: yes i know that  x distribution will be, $(1-p)^{m-1}p$ for ex qqqp, but when i find  Y should it be $qqqpqqp - >q^3p . q^2p$ ? so $q^5p^2$? ,  how do you got $n-1$? i count ed it using margiinal distribution definition for py https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution and it give same result but im not sure why it gave same result(?) why you sum from m=1 to m=n-1?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean. "how do you got $n-1$?..." Where do I get that? Do you mean the conditional distribution ($\frac1{n-1}$)?

Comment: i mean here $P(Y=n)=\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}P(X=m,Y=n)=(n-1)p^2q^{n-2}$ , if i just count like you said, $q^5p^2$ this produce $ q^{n-2}p^2$ , why you have to sum 1 until up $m=n-1$?

Comment: Do you agree that $\{Y=n\}=\{X=1,Y=n\}\cup\cdots\cup\{X=n-1,Y=n\}$? A union of $n-1$ events that all have probability $p^2q^{n-2}$.

Comment: what i understand, $P(X=m,Y=n)=P(X=m) * P(Y=n|X=m)=p^2q^{n-2}$,  so this means probability of second head appear in n given that first head appear in m is the same as P(Y=n)(?) i dont know how to relate this to Y and why we have to relate this to X? ,  for example when Y=7(second head), we try to find all possibility if x=1,2,3,4, until n-1(before first head appear) and sum that? which mean same as finding marginal distribution of Y?